# Contar nulls en data frame y encontrar la columna con mayor cantidad

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, null

Por favor necesito encontrar que columna tiene la mayor cantidad de `Nan`.

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Mary', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy','Anne'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Smith', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze','Lynn'], 
        'age': [42, np.nan, 36, 24, 73,'23'], 
        'sex': ['m', np.nan, 'f', 'm', 'f','f'], 
        'preTestScore': [4, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan],
        'postTestScore': [25, np.nan, np.nan, 62, 70, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'sex', 'preTestScore',       'postTestScore'])
```

Con `isnull().sum()` me cuenta en todo el `DataFrame` **¿Cómo hago para encontrar la columna con mayor cantidad de nulos?**

¿Algo así?:

`max = max(df.isnull().sum())`

Answer (score 1):

## Introducción

Pues has hecho lo más complejo de la respuesta que es darse cuenta de que `.isnull()` es un método que devuelve `False` si NO es nulo y `True` si es nulo. Por lo que después como `False` es cero y `True` es uno, sumas y ya tienes la cantidad de nulos.

## Respuesta

Puedes ordenar los valores haciendo un `.sort_values()` y después ir al indice usando el método `.index` y coger el último.

Cojo el código de tu ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Mary', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy','Anne'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Smith', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze','Lynn'], 
        'age': [42, np.nan, 36, 24, 73,'23'], 
        'sex': ['m', np.nan, 'f', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
        'preTestScore': [4, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan],
        'postTestScore': [25, np.nan, np.nan, 62, 70, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'sex', 'preTestScore',       'postTestScore'])

print(df.isnull().sum().sort_values().index[-1])
```

**Salida**:

```
'postTestScore'
```

Darse cuenta también, que si utilizas un número distinto de`.index[-1]` al indizar, puedes seleccionar las *N* columnas con mayor cantidad de `NaN`